# Simplify function with normalized vector

Tags: simplifying-expressions, vector

I made a very simple case:

```
testF[x_, y_, z_] = x^2 + y^2 + z^2
Simplify[testF[x, y, z]]
```

If {x, y, z} is normalized, the simplified result should just be 1. How could I specify this condition/assumption?

Comment: `Simplify[testF[x, y, z], Assumptions -> x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1]` works on my end.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to local situation and needs of its poster. 

Comment: @m_goldberg do you remember why this question was reopened? Because I can't cast a close vote again.

Comment: @Kuba. No, don't remember. I will write up Narain's comment as community wiki answer. You can up-vote it to get the question off unanswered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rahul Narain wrote in a comment,

```
testF[x_, y_, z_] = x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
Simplify[testF[x, y, z], Assumptions -> x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

This may seem trivial, but it precisely expresses the condition for normality.